# How and when to use teminology and trivia tags?

Tags: support, tags

- How and when to use [terminology](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [trivia](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tags?
- What is the difference between them?

Give some easily understandable explanation.

For ex, both these tags are used in this [post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2822/why-is-darren-lehmann-called-boof).

How they are apt with that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[terminology](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is used when you are referring to some words or expressions used in a sport, e.g. "the red zone" in american football or "offside trap" in football. The proposed use of the tag is to ask for clarifications or explanations of the meaning of the terminology.

[trivia](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) is exactly what trivia means, trivial pieces of information referring often to less known facts regarding some sports. For instance, "who is the youngest Portuguese football player to score a goal in a World Cup?" would be a very typical trivia question.

Trivia questions rarely have any other purpose than quenching someone's curiosity, in other words, there is little "learning value" but they are often fun or interesting.

---

so all that said, the question you link to uses both tags and I believe that's because the OP is after the meaning of a term s/he has heard. The way I see it, the fact the question is about the nickname given to a coach justifies the [trivia](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) and that the possibility for the nickname to originate from some jargon or slang related to the sport justifies the [terminology](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

Hope this helps